# How to trigger gitlab pipeline test manually?

Tags: gitlab-ci, pipeline

I would like to ask is there any way I can trigger the gitlab pipeline test manually? For example I just want to play around with the .gitlab-ci.yml script without commiting change to the original .gitlab-ci.yml file.

Comment: Will committing to a .gitlab-ci.yml on a test branch is an option?
This way you can also track your tests and merge to the original .gitlab-ci.yml or delete the branch once done.

Comment: I guess that the only way. I am planning doing the same. Thank you